# Sails js 'and' query

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I have a big data collection of products. I'm looking for products that have 'spaghetti' in the name, but don't have 'mix'  in the name, using sails js. I tried a couple things, here is one.

```
Product.find({
  where: {
    name: {'contains': 'spaghetti'},
    name: {'!': 'mix'}
  }
})
```

This works like an OR query, where is will find everything with either spaghetti in it OR not mix in it. Which of course returns way more than just the spaghetti. What I need instead is for it to query AND instead of OR. Preferably without just executing find/where again on top of the already found data, as I assume that will take way longer.

I feel like it should be easy to change from OR into AND. But I've been looking everywhere and I can't find anything about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an `AND` query with the same attribute used twice like this:

```
Product.find({
  and: [
    {name: {'contains': 'spaghetti'}},
    {name: {'contains': 'mix'}}
  ]
})
```

However, `name: {'!': 'mix'}` means `name != 'mix'`, i.e. "not equal to". Unfortunately "not contains" queries are currently not supported in Waterline – you'd have to use [query()](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/query) or [native()](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/native) for that. See Waterline issues [#1296](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/1296), [#666](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/666), [#22](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/22) for more details.

Comment: I see. Well in that case I guess I'll be working .query()  anyway. Thanks. Also, I tried that code you gave but it doesn't work. When I try sails gives an error saying "You have an error in your SQL syntax" "near [object Object],[object Object]". But I guess since I need to use .query() anyway it's not really a problem to me.

Comment: @Ozitiho OK, the query works for me so it might be an adapter-specific issue (I tested only with the default `sails-disk`) or a version-specific issue (I tested with current latest Sails.js version, 0.12.3). But yeah, `query()` for now.